# Sinatra app using HAML not preserving indentation

Tags: sinatra, haml

I am developing a basic Sinatra app. I implemented all the views using HAML, but have noticed that the output does not preserve the indentation.

For example, the following:

```
%html
  %head
    %script{ :src => '/main.js' }
```

is rendered in the browser as

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='/main.js'></script>
</head>
</html>
```

It's been a while since I used HAML for anything, but my understanding is that preserving indentation is one of the points of HAML as a tool. So this result strikes me as particularly unusual.

How do I fix this?

Ruby 2.7.1p8, HAML 5.2.0, Sinatra 2.1.0.

Comment: https://github.com/haml/haml/pull/894

Comment: Well that's disgusting. I was using HAML partially to get the pretty output. I guess I'll figure out something else. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Slim has very similar syntax and still includes this possibility